# Expo React Native: Bad image quality when saving image from remote uri to camera roll

Tags: react-native, expo

With Expo on iOS, I'm using the following code to download an image from a remote uri to the FileSystem and then create an asset to save it on the camera roll of the user phone:

```js
const { uri: path } = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
    remoteUrl,
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + "test.jpg"
);

const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(path);
```

When using the local uri with an Image component, the image quality is great. But when I look at the image in the camera roll, the image is blur and quality way below what I see from the file.

I have checked the image size saved locally versus the file saved remotely and they are the same (around 1.1MB).

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Facing that too. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way using [expo-image-manipulator](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/). 'Compress: 1' being the best quality you can get. Then saving the asset with [expo-media-library](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/). No more loss of quality.

```js
const { uri } = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
   path, //path to your local asset
   [],
   { compress: 1, format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.PNG }
);

const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
```